# Getting error when compiling latex file (in `.aux file`)

Tags: compiling

When trying  to compile my latex file (which is rather large, so I don't post it here), I'm getting a  weird error:

```
./main.aux:1: Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ...@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@
                                                  ^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^...
```

This appears multiple times in my `main.log` file, but I don't really  understand  what it means and how to resolve it.

Comment: Delete the aux and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have tried this several times know, but after adding some text the same error occurs again.

Comment: Well then something breaks the aux. But as you are giving up to no info about your document and how you compile it is not really possible to help you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I could upload the `.tex` file and give you the link to it, but I figured that one would probably not look at it since it's >2000 lines

Comment: deletes the aux, compile once with what ever engine you use (*not* with some system like latexmk or texify) and then show the log-file somehow.